# HttpActionContext unique request identifier

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am running some load tests on my Web API application, and am trying to find a way to identify each request as it comes in to the methods `OnActionExecuted` and `OnActionExecuting`

My question is, within the objects `HttpActionExecutedContext` and `HttpActionContext` is there some kind of unique identifier I can obtain to identify an individual request.

I have tried adding a unix timestamp to my query string, but the requests are often coming in at the same time so this does not help.

I am hoping these objects have some kind of property?

Comment: You could add a scoped class using Dependency Injection that generates a new Guid in it's constructor or similar.

Comment: @Silvermind do you have an example?

Comment: Would a logging solution work for you. Serilog has an enricher that  will log incomming request and theri details including time taken parameters and all that good stuff. I can provide more details if that is something you want to try

Comment: @npo that may be helpful

Comment: Are you using .net framework or .net core?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a scoped class with a generated identifier using Dependency Injection.
A scoped class is created once per request.

```
public class IdentifiedScope
{
    public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}

// Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IdentifiedScope>();
}

// Controller
public MyController(IdentifiedScope identifiedScope)
{
    this.identifiedScope = identifiedScope;
}

// Usage in an ActionFilter
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context,
                                                  ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    var identifiedScope = 
           context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IdentifiedScope>();
}
```

Comment: This answer assumes ASP.NET Core is being used.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Right. Assumption is the mother of all... I will ask for clarification ;).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check requests execution time you could use serilog

Setup this code on your statup.cs

```
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
          .Enrich.With<HttpRequestIdEnricher>()
          .Enrich.With<HttpRequestNumberEnricher>()
          .Enrich.With<HttpSessionIdEnricher>()
          .Enrich.With<HttpRequestTraceIdEnricher>()
          .WriteTo.Debug()
          .CreateLogger();
```

> ```
> HttpRequestIdEnricher
> HttpRequestNumberEnricher
> HttpSessionIdEnricher
> HttpRequestTraceIdEnricher
> ```
>
> These might be separate nuget packages just seraching for htem if they
>   are don't come with Serilog

```
Install Serilog
and Serilog.Sinks.Debug
```

The for each request you should see the result in the console

> [05:06:14 INF] HTTP GET /api/v1/blablabla/blablablaresponded 401 in
>   7530ms

Hope it helps